# Userform Checkboxes to populate word doc and determine next form opened

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I’ve been trying to use some userforms with checkboxes to populate a word document and have hit a snag.  Let’s say I am letting the user select their favorite animals from a checkbox list:

- [ ] Monkeys
- [ ] Elephants
- [ ] Cats

From that, if the user selects them it would populate on a line.  If they select more than one, it should have the proper format (Monkeys, Elephants, and Cats or Monkeys and Cats ect.)

In addition to that I would want an additional form to pop up (or forms?) based on which boxes that were checked.  So, if someone checked Monkeys and Cats a box would pop up with something like this (or one form after another if this can’t happen)

What is your favorite thing about

Monkeys

They eat bananas

They make funny noises

They swing in trees

Cats
They are jerks
They meow
They sleep a lot

From there, it would populate using the same logic as above with commas and “and”.

I’ve tried a couple different codes to populate the date from the checkboxes and keep getting errors.  Either I can’t select more than 2 or if I do only the last one selected is inserted.  I’m using a bookmark to insert the data if that matters.

```
Private Sub cmdFavAnimalNext_Click()
Dim strAnimal As String
If cbxMonkey = True Then strAnimal = "Monkeys, "
If cbxElephants = True Then strAnimal = strAnimal And "Elephants, "
If cbxCats = True Then strAnimal = strAnimal And "Cats, "


'Clean up formatting

With ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("Animal").Range.Text = strAnimal
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Unload Me


'Next Userform based on checks
```

Comment: Text concatenation uses `&`, not `And`  Plus you need some more logic to determine where to place commas and "and"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Then strAnimal = strAnimal And "Elephants, "
> ```

The `And` operator can't be used that way. `And` is a logical/bitwise operator used in `Boolean` expressions or bitwise `And` operations.

To concatenate strings, use the `&` operator. The `+` operator can also be used, but it's better to use `&` since `+` also serves as the "addition" operator, while `&` is only ever used for string concatenations.

Comment: That explains it. I had no idea that & was different than "And".  Thanks!